# Getting nullpointer exception with listview setadapter

Tags: android

I searched other topics and came to the conclusion that my listview was the cause of the null pointer exception but i cant figure anyway to fix it.

here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/instantme_check_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.88" >
</ListView>
```

left out the rest to make it less messy and my code is

```
public class instantme_check extends Activity {
  InputStream is = null;
  TextView name;
  TextView content;
  EditText entername;
  EditText entercontent;
  private ListView list;
      ...

  name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instantme_check_name);
  content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instantme_check_message);
  entername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.instantme_check_entername);
  entercontent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.instantme_check_entermessage);
  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.instantme_check_list);
      ...

  listAdapter4 = new displayadapter4();
  list.setAdapter(listAdapter4);
```

as for the display adapter class( i already used it in two other parts of the code and it worked so i assume its fine)

```
 public class displayadapter4 extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    displayadapter4()
    {
        super(instantme_check.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, course);
    }       
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView size1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.size);
        size1.setText("Subject: " + subject[position]);
        TextView size2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.size2);
        size2.setText("Message: " + message[position]);
        TextView size3 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.size3);
        size3.setText("From: " + user[position]);

        return(row);        
    }

}
```

It keeps giving nullpointer exception although the data i put into the arrayadapter i am sure is fine since i used Log.i to verify it.

As for my error log

```
    04-07 00:33:10.714: W/dalvikvm(273): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.Assist.assistme.instantme_check$displayadapter4.getView(instantme_check.java:172)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-07 00:33:10.734: E/AndroidRuntime(273):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 00:33:12.884: D/dalvikvm(289): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 806 objects / 57952 bytes in 66ms
```

Sorry for the really lengthy post. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/size3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which line is instantme_check.java:172?

Comment: Does `row.xml` actually have a TextView with `@+id/label`?

Comment: @m0skit0:line 173 is View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

Comment: @sam yeah it does, i used it for another listview in another activity and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your LogCat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
```

The problem is that the View id that you passed to ArrayAdapter's super constructor, here:

```
super(instantme_check.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, course);
```

Doesn't exist in your layout, you can read through the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource%28int%2Candroid.view.View%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cint%29) to see exactly how and why this causes the NullPointerException.

The solution is simple: use a different id or add this TextView to your layout.

Comment: By View id do you mean the R.id.label? I have a replica of this code in two other parts of the app and they also use the row.xml, exactly like this and they work fine. Thats why i am so confused about this one. EDIT: i tried using another ID, still gave the same error.

Comment: I created a whole new TextView in row.xml and it works! I am selecting this as the best answer since it gave me the hint to find it. Thanks much :)

Comment: I'm glad my advice led you to a solution, thank you for accepting it.  I see you posted `row.xml`, which has a TextView with `@+id/label`... sometime Eclipse gets confused maybe you only needed to clean your project.  But you have working code now so it doesn't matter too much.